# debugging in gdb - how to know if test succeeded

Tags: assembly, terminal, gdb

I'm currently writing an assembly code for class. I'm using vmware (debugging with sasm). I'm trying to debug it through gdb from the terminal. when running my program with gdb, it gives the following message:

```css
[Inferior 1 (process 46681) exited normally]
```

[image]

and I'm not sure what should I do, it means that the program is running without memory leaks\segmentation faults etc? I didn't find any info about this message after running google search. perhaps I don't know how to look for it, and if anyone could refer me to a place to read about it, I will be very grateful.

thank you very much for your help!

Comment: We don't know what you mean by "test". This means the program ended and returned an exit code of 0.

Comment: It means no segfaults, yes. The program might still be doing the wrong thing of course.

Comment: GDB doesn't check for memory leaks.  Use a tool like Valgrind for that.  If you want to debug your program, run it with a breakpoint at the top of `main` using `start` instead of `run`.  Or `starti` to stop at the first user-space instruction (the top of `_start` in a static executable.)

Comment: thank you very much everyone, just wanted to make sure no segfaults.